# ORA-00913 - "too many values" error message on correlated query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on this query trying to get it to return only one column that will be passed to outer query. Question is how can I rewrite this query so that it only returns one column so I can then join it to the main query to eliminate the above error?

```
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT JIN.TITLE,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
          ORDER BY EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT DESC) AS ROWRANK
      FROM WC_HIRED_INTERNS_FA HIN
      INNER JOIN WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F EIN
      ON HIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = EIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
      INNER JOIN WC_JOB_INFORMATION_D JIN
      ON EIN.JOB_INFO_ROW_WID  = JIN.ROW_WID
      WHERE EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_STS_NAME = 'Hired - External'
      AND EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_STEP_NAME = 'Hire'
      AND JIN.JOB_FAMILY_NAME IN ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other')
      AND JIN.TITLE  NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns',
        'Student Ambassador')
      AND  HIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = H.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
    ) ac
    where ROWRANK = 1 
  ) AS ACCEPTEDTITLE
```

Complete code after trying to apply Aleksj's suggestion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,
  H.PARENT_PI_NUMBER,
  H.ASSOCIATE_NAME,
  J.JOB_FAMILY_NAME,
  J.ORGANIZATION_NAME,
  J.TITLE,
  E.CONTEST_NUMBER,
  E.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT OFFER_DATE,
  (
    SELECT JIN.TITLE
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
        ORDER BY EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT DESC) AS ROWRANK
      FROM WC_HIRED_INTERNS_FA HIN
      INNER JOIN WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F EIN ON HIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = EIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
      INNER JOIN WC_JOB_INFORMATION_D JIN ON EIN.JOB_INFO_ROW_WID = JIN.ROW_WID
      WHERE JIN.JOB_FAMILY_NAME IN ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other')
      AND EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_STS_NAME = 'Hired - External'
      AND EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_STEP_NAME = 'Hire'
      AND JIN.TITLE NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns',
        'Student Ambassador')
      AND HIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = H.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
    ) ac
    where ROWRANK = 1
  ) AS ACCEPTEDTITLE
FROM WC_HIRED_INTERNS_FA H
INNER JOIN WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F E ON H.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = E.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
INNER JOIN WC_JOB_INFORMATION_D J ON E.JOB_INFO_ROW_WID = J.ROW_WID
WHERE E.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT E.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT --limit 1
  FROM WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F E
  INNER JOIN WC_HIRED_INTERNS_FA H ON H.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = E.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
  INNER JOIN WC_JOB_INFORMATION_D J ON E.JOB_INFO_ROW_WID = J.ROW_WID
  WHERE J.JOB_FAMILY_NAME IN ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other')
  AND E.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_STS_NAME = 'Extended'
  AND E.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_STEP_NAME = 'Offer'
  AND J.TITLE NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns',
    'Student Ambassador')
);
```

Comment: If you want to select only one column, then select that one column, not several.

Comment: How do I re write the query above to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Maybe you only need to edit `*` into `title`

Comment: meaning title*?

Comment: `select title from` instead of `select * from`

Comment: I had tried that but I get an erro (ORA-00904: "JIN"."TITLE": invalid identifie)

Comment: The issue is somewhere else then; what does the alias `JIN` refer to? a table in the external query? posting the complete code could help

Comment: Maybe some confusion with J and JIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aleksej said in a comment, you need to change `*` to `title`; based on your later comments you seem to have moved the `jin.title` reference out of the inner query completely, and left the prefix.

So instead of

```
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT JIN.TITLE,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
          ORDER BY EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT DESC) AS ROWRANK
...
    ) ac
    where ROWRANK = 1 
  ) AS ACCEPTEDTITLE
```

or your modified version:

```
  (
    SELECT JIN.TITLE
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
        ORDER BY EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT DESC) AS ROWRANK
...
    ) ac
    where ROWRANK = 1
  ) AS ACCEPTEDTITLE
```

you need:

```
  (
    SELECT TITLE
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        JIN.TITLE,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EIN.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
          ORDER BY EIN.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT DESC)AS ROWRANK
...
    ) ac
    where ROWRANK = 1 
) AS ACCEPTEDTITLE
```

I've commented on your previous questions that I think your use of subqueries and repeated code needs to be reevaluated and simplified. The use of `DISTINCT` is often an indication that something isn't quite right too.

---

You still haven't provided an MCVE but with a few assumptions about what you're doing and your data, it looks like you want something like:

```
select h.pi_candidate_num,
  h.parent_pi_number,
  h.associate_name,
  j.job_family_name,
  j.organization_name,
  j.title,
  e.contest_number,
  max(case when e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_sts_name = 'Extended'
            and e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_step_name = 'Offer'
           then e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_creation_dt end) as offer_date,
  max(case when e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_sts_name = 'Hired - External'
            and e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_step_name = 'Hire'
           then e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_creation_dt end) as accepted_title,
  max(case when e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_sts_name = 'Hired - External'
            and e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_step_name = 'Hire'
           then e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_creation_dt end) as hire_date
from wc_hired_interns_fa h
join wc_application_event_f e on h.pi_candidate_num = e.pi_candidate_num
join wc_job_information_d j on e.job_info_row_wid = j.row_wid
where j.job_family_name in ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other')
and (
 (e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_sts_name = 'Extended'
  and e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_step_name = 'Offer')
 or (e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_sts_name = 'Hired - External'
  and e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_step_name = 'Hire')
)
and j.title not in ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns',
  'Student Ambassador')
group by h.pi_candidate_num,
  h.parent_pi_number,
  h.associate_name,
  j.job_family_name,
  j.organization_name,
  j.title,
  e.contest_number;
```

which should, I think, show every offer extended to the candidates, and against the one(s) they accepted (if any) it will repeat that title (which doesn't seem useful but was what your subquery was looking for) and as it might be useful the hire date.

Untested of course, but might point you in a new direction to get what you need.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, although that seems to clear the error, it introduces another issue with the query results set. The resultant column expected results was one row per each occurrence of title, but now its repeating results for each occurrence of title. Any suggestions on what I need to trick to get just one row?

Comment: It looks like you're only correlating the subquery on the candidate number, so you'll see the same accepted title against every row for that candidate. You could maybe add the connect number to the correlation? I've added a different approach you could try. it still isn't clear what you actually want to retrieve, and as I said before without an MCVE and expected results we're largely guessing.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do. I have to point out, your suggestions are working only thing is the extra row but here's is what I am trying to accomplish: the outer query is supposed to return all the job offers that we extended to each candidate  , the inner querry is supposed to return the one job that we finally hired the candidate out of all the offers we might have extended. At the present time, the outer query is doing what I expect it to do , but inner querry although its returning the correct values, its repeating those values .

Comment: I still don't know what is repeating or where, or where you're seeing an extra row. It seems like there should be one row for every offer made to every candidate, and every row for a candidate will show the same `acceptedtitle` value, which is for the one job they were hired for. So that `acceptedtitle` is repeated, is that what you mean? That seems to be what you want though, and I can't see what else you would want it to show. And again, we can't see your tables or data or current or expected results, so there's only so much we can speculate about.

Comment: Anyway, if this has fixed the error you were getting then anything else is out of scope for this question.

Comment: excuse my not responding earlier to this: what does MCVE mean? You are correct there is one row for every offer made but the offer accepted should be only one row. That's what the inner query is supposed to return  but its returning multiple rows of the accepted offer

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I've linked to that help centre article on the two previous questions I've answered.

Comment: Do you mean it's showing the same accepted title against multiple rows for the same candidate? That's what I referred to before. Exactly the same subquery is running for every row for each candidate, as that is the only correlated value. Adding `AND EIN.CONTEXT_NUMBER = E.CONTEST_NUMBER` inside the subquery might might help, but it's hard to tell. Or try the alternative query I included.

Comment: Do you mean it's showing the same accepted title against multiple rows for the same candidate?  Correct, its showing same accepted job title on multiple rows. I tried addint contest number and that did not make a difference , I have also tried the alternate querry you had provided and its not giving the expected results.

Comment: Maybe you need `job_info_row_wid` in the correlation too? Again, we're guessing, we don't know your data... I've done all i can with the information available. As before, if you get further and then get stuck again, ask a new question.